# colorbox breaks on rel attribute when bxslider is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox, bxslider

After much debugging I came to the conclusion these two libraries are colliding. I tested them both separate and they work but when used together (and there is a rel attribute things break)

How to reproduce

- If the link has a rel or $('something').colorbox({rel:'something'});
- $('somethingelse').bxSlider(...);

colorbox will fail when clicking on any image that has colorbox (not just the shared options) With:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rel' of undefined

Offending lines of code are:

> ```
>       if (settings.rel !== 'nofollow') {
>           $related = $('.' + boxElement).filter(function () {
>               var relRelated = $.data(this, colorbox).rel || this.rel;
>               return (relRelated === settings.rel);
>           });
> ```

I found a similar issue [Do I use jQuery noconflict to avoid plugins conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098914/do-i-use-jquery-noconflict-to-avoid-plugins-conflict) however the effect was different. Yet the cause seems similar. According to someone answering that question the problem is that bxSlider whipes out the $.data() set by colorbox.

So my questions are:

- Is there a way around this?
- Is it a bug in colorbox?
- Is it a bug in bxSlider?

Answer (score 1):

I know its been ages since this question asked but I had the similar problem and after much struggling the error for me was that I was calling colorbox before bxslider, I change the order of calls and it works as a charm. Maybe someone will be helped by this.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code I can't tell what your trying to do. Your `$('something').colorbox({rel:'something'});` looks a bit strange and I can't tell if your inserting classes, id or an actual rel attribute value. You may want to review colorbox's rel option(rel:'something') and how it behaves. See http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

There are no issues that I see with using those two plugins together. I tried it [on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ovucuz/11/edit#javascript,html,live) and it works fine with no errors.

**See here for yourself:** http://jsbin.com/ovucuz/11/edit#javascript,html,live